# Accessing calloced array in GAS assembly

Tags: c, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have a C function which allocated some memory to an array that is going to be filled with natural numbers up to a certain N.

Lets say,

```
N = 10;
array = calloc(N, sizeof(int));
```

I then call upon an assembly function that I have written, however I don't seem to be able to access the array fields. I manage to find the value of N which is located at 8(%ebp), and I have checked with GDB that it really equals to the N set in the C code.

However, when I try to access the first element in the array, and move it to, for example %esi, the value is not zero as it should be.

That I do by using the following code

```
movl 12(%ebp), %esi
```

EDIT; I do of course fill the array with natural numbers before calling the assembly function. I just did not want to type in the for loop here.

As I understands it, the parentheses de-refrences the first element of the array, and copies that to esi, however, esi contains only a huge negative number when I use info registers on a breakpoint set after this code in GDB.

So, How do I access arrays that is calloced beforehand, and passed into an assembly function? Is it not possible to derefrence, and copy that single element?

Here is the C function that calls upon the assembly function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int n = 10;

    int *array = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    int i, j;

    // Populate array up to N
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        array[i] = 2 + i;
    }

    printf("Array: %d \n", sizeof(array));

    // Run sievs
    sievs_assembly(n, array);

    // print prime
    print_prime(array, n);

    // Free mem
    free(array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I dont want to post the assembly file as a whole, since it is a school project, and I'm not asking for help solving the assessment, only the specific problem. How to derefrence an array item.

The function prototype is

```
extern void sievs_assembly(int n, int *a);
```

I thought that since the pointer *a is an int array, and the first argument N is located at 8(%ebp), that the first array element would be 12(%ebp).

How do I actually get to the value if its not enough to just do movl 12(%ebp), %esi

Comment: You have not shown your function, not even its prototype. I will assume you are passing in a pointer, so you need to dereference. `12(%ebp)` only dereferences `ebp` to get to the argument, it doesn't dereference the pointer itself.

Comment: I will edit and post everything. The prototype is func(int n, int *a)

Comment: How do I derefrence the pointer itself?

Comment: You have so far loaded the pointer into `%esi`, to dereference it, do `movl (%esi), %esi`. Side note: according to standard calling convention, you have to preserve `esi` (among others), so make sure you do that.

Comment: Yes, I have preserved ebx, edi, and esi.

Comment: Another question: How do i Change a variable in the array? Did not work with just moving 0 to esi after the derefrencing proccess. I figure i must somehow move it to the location of the memory address in the array element, but how?

Comment: Yes, for example using `movl $42, (%esi)`. That's assuming `esi` still holds the pointer, ie. you haven't loaded a value there.

Comment: Well, thanks everybody. I have completed my asignment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
movl 12(%ebp), %esi
```

you have moved the memory adress of your array into %esi. The value of the first element is what this adress is pointing to. To get that you can use:

```
movl (%esi), %eax
```

This moves the first element into %eax. The brackets basicly mean "what %esi is pointing to". The size of an int is probably 4 bytes for you (you could check with 'sizeof(int)'). So to acces the next element you could use:

```
movl 4(%esi), %eax
```

Which moves the next element into %eax.

I've also made an example program which prints 2 values from an array. Note: I made it for windows.

```
.macro print str         #macro name is 'print'. 1 argument: 'str'
    pushl \str           #argument names are escaped
    call _printf
    addl $4, %esp        #pop the arguments
.endm

.macro printf str fs     #can't overload macro names, so let's call this one 'printf'
    pushl \str
    pushl \fs            #printing numbers requires a format srting
    call _printf
    addl $8, %esp
.endm

.text
.global _main

_main:                  #actual program, '_main' becomes 'WinMain@16'
    pushl %ebp          #push frame
    movl %esp, %ebp

    movl $array, %esi   #Move array pointer to $esi.

    #print what %esi is pointing to
    printf (%esi), $fs

    #print a newline
    print $nl

    #print what %esi+4 is pointing to. Since a long is 4 bytes
    #The next element of the array is 4 bytes further than the first
    printf 4(%esi), $fs

    movl $0, %eax       #move 0 to return register
    leave               #pop frame
    ret                 #return

.data

fs: .string "%i"    #Format string
nl: .string "\n"    #New Line

array:              #Some array
    .long 1,2
```

This program prints the output:

```
1
2
```

**Edit**:
Since this got some attention, I thought I'd update the answer with some macros.

And explain the `_` prefixes on c library calls and `main`; I'm compiling on windows with MinGW, which requires those prefixes to avoid getting undefined reference errors. On linux they're not needed.

For further documentation about [macros](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html) and GAS see: [using as](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/)

Comment: Thanks. My only confusion were how to access the pointers. I thought that I could do it in one instruction, however it seems that I first have to move the mem address, and then derefrence it. Also, when changing values in a pointer, it was as easy as moving a value into a derefrenced mem address. Thanks anyway

Comment: I wasn't really sure how much you already knew, since you didn't post any assembly code (very understandable though). So I thought I'd try to be as thorough as possible to make sure you understood everything :). Secondly, I also thought about other users who might look at this, and not know as much as you do, so that's another reason I included the (somewhat excessive) example. Thirdly, I believe any knowledge transfered should have an example to go with it, so you can link the new knowledge to something you already knew. Anyways I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

A little bit modificated. Compile it by gcc -m32 -g -o foo foo.s

```
.data

fs: .string "%i"    #Format string
nl: .string "\n"    #New Line

array: .long 1,2

.text
.global main

main:

pushl %ebp          #push frame
movl %esp, %ebp

movl $array, %esi   #Move array pointer to $esi.

pushl (%esi)        #Push what %esi is pointing to
pushl $fs           #push the format string
call printf        #call printf
addl $8, %esp       #pop the arguments

pushl $nl           #print a new line
call printf
addl $4, %esp

pushl 4(%esi)       #push what %esi+4 is pointing to. Since a long is 4 bytes
pushl $fs           #The next element is 4 bytes further than the first
call printf
addl $8, %esp

pushl $nl           #print a new line
call printf
addl $4, %esp

pushl $0
call exit
```